# How ignore hibernate error and continue insert data?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have some method in my DAO class:

```
public void insertAVAYAcmCDRs(List<AvayaCmCdr> cdrList) {
        AvayaCmCdr aCdrList1 = null;
        try {
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            for (AvayaCmCdr aCdrList : cdrList) {
                aCdrList1 = aCdrList;
                em.persist(aCdrList);
            }
            em.getTransaction().commit();
            em.clear();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.log(Level.INFO, "Exception in  task time={0}. Exception message = {1}.", new Object[]{aCdrList1.getDate(), e.getMessage()});
        }
    }
```

I tried save all array entities to DB. But in DB i have uniqe index - it does not allow to insert duplicate rows. It work normaly on DB side but i have some error in java.

```
a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session:
```

I get this error on 2 step of cycle. I print this object and found dublicate in DB.

I want ignore this error and continue insert data or somehow handle the error.

if this row already in the database i want ignore and skip it and continue insert

Comment: This error is pretty self-explanatory: Hibernate is being told to persist an object whose id value it has already seen on another object in the same session.  Can you modify your business logic so that this does not happen?

Comment: When you say "But in DB i have uniqe index - it does not allow to insert duplicate rows. It work normaly on DB side but i have some error in java." what do you mean? If the DB has a unique constraint then it won't allow you to violate it, from Java or otherwise.

Comment: I created an index that does not allow me to insert duplicate rows. I just want to skip them and continue to insert the remaining rows

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen all my objects has id = 0 when i insert. And in DB i set autoincrement to this column

Answer (score 0):

Why are you assigning this aCdrList1 = aCdrList ? Is there any specific reason?
you can save aCdrList  object. Use below one

```
em.saveOrUpdate(aCdrList);
```

or

```
em.merge(aCdrList);
```